# Convert Byte String to alpha-numeric char array in java?

Tags: java, string, byte, alphanumeric

My question is, I guess, quite simple :

How to convert a Byte to alpha-numeric char array (String) in java ?

I tried this but it gives me back an error on netbeans :

```
 byte[] b = "test".getBytes("ASCII");
 String test = new String(b,"ASCII");
```

UPDATE : 
I am actually using this code :

```
    byte[] b = "test".getBytes("ASCII");
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    String bla = new String(md.digest(b), "ASCII");
```

But once I try to use for other stuff which requires String with ASCII, I receive the following errors like "This is not ASCII". 
I don't really understand, actually.

When I try to print it I got something weird like "2Q�h/�k�����"

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: OK, that `byte` vs. `byte[]` was just a typo... What's the error you're getting?

Comment: It doesn't want to compile according to netbeans... I don't understand. When I try to print b I got this kind of result : 2Q�h/�k�����U�b=���u����(��>T�

Comment: Are you sure your original `String` is ASCII? Please provide an example.

Comment: works for me, what error are you getting?

Comment: @nkr His original string is `"test"`...

Comment: @brimborium: woops :) But it works for me. Maybe he converts another string in his code.

Comment: "Not suitable constructor found for String" us the error I got

Comment: According to the documentation, the name of the required Charset is "US-ASCII". Other Charsets are optional. I'm not sure why you would get the error you're getting if that was the problem, though.

Comment: Topic updated to make it more clear.*

Comment: No, you don't update it, you keep modifying the question.

Comment: Sorry I thought it would have been more simple

Answer (score 1):

You're close :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException { //you should throw or catch this exception
   byte[] b = "test".getBytes("ASCII"); // And you must declare a byte array
   String test = new String(b,"ASCII");

   System.out.println(test); // Will output "test"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your edits I think you want to generate a `SHA-256` hash of a given `String`.

```
try {
    byte[] b = "test".getBytes("ASCII");
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] hashBytes = md.digest(b);
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.length; i++) {
        hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & hashBytes[i]));
    }
    System.out.println(hexString);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```